# React native custom push object notification not working?

Tags: android, react-native, push-notification, notifications

I have created push notification in React native. i am able to get notification if i test from this site : https://pushtry.com/

But now if i try with my custom notification object. push notification not working :

> {"_data":{"created":"21 Aug '19 09:24
>   AM","carpark":"0","message":"Your deals will be expired soon !\n1.
>   This is Exclsive DOB Deals - SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem Date : 21
>   Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug '19\n2. This is Exclsive DOB Deals -
>   SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem Date : 21 Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug
>   '19\n3. This is Exclsive DOB Deals - SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem
>   Date : 20 Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug
>   '19","title":"Notification"},"_from":"759251633792","_messageId":"0:1566810334866452%98a4273ef9fd7ecd","_sentTime":1566810334859,"_ttl":3600}

I have used following code for this :

```
async componentDidMount() {
        if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
            await Helpers.requestPermission()
                .then((result) => {
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(result)) //result==success then permission granted
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    alert(error) //result==permission not granted
                });

        }

        else {

        }

        this.checkPermission();
        this.createNotificationListeners();

        const notificationOpen: NotificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        if (notificationOpen) {
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
            var seen = [];
            alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function (key, val) {
                if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                    if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    seen.push(val);
                }
                return val;
            }));
        }
        const channel = new firebase.notifications.Android.Channel('test-channel', 'Test Channel', firebase.notifications.Android.Importance.Max)
            .setDescription('My apps test channel');// Create the channel
        firebase.notifications().android.createChannel(channel);
        this.notificationDisplayedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationDisplayed((notification: Notification) => {
            // Process your notification as required
            // ANDROID: Remote notifications do not contain the channel ID. You will have to specify this manually if you'd like to re-display the notification.
        });
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification: Notification) => {
            // Process your notification as required
            notification
                .android.setChannelId('test-channel')
                .android.setSmallIcon('ic_launcher');
            firebase.notifications()
                .displayNotification(notification);

        });
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
            // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
            const action = notificationOpen.action;
            // Get information about the notification that was opened
            const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
            var seen = [];
            alert(JSON.stringify(notification.data, function (key, val) {
                if (val != null && typeof val == "object") {
                    if (seen.indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                        return;
                    }
                    seen.push(val);
                }
                return val;
            }));
            firebase.notifications().removeDeliveredNotification(notification.notificationId);

        });



    }

    //1
    async checkPermission() {
        const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission();
        if (enabled) {
            this.getToken();
        } else {
            this.requestPermission();
        }
    }

    //3
    async getToken() {
        let fcmToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('fcmToken');
        if (!fcmToken) {
            fcmToken = await firebase.messaging().getToken();
            if (fcmToken) {
                // user has a device token
                console.log('Token ------ > ' + fcmToken);
                await Helpers.saveInPref(constant.PREF_DEVICE_TOKEN, fcmToken);
            }
        }
    }

    //2
    async requestPermission() {
        try {
            await firebase.messaging().requestPermission();
            // User has authorised
            this.getToken();
        } catch (error) {
            // User has rejected permissions
            console.log('permission rejected');
        }
    }
async createNotificationListeners() {
        /*
        * Triggered when a particular notification has been received in foreground
        * */
        this.notificationListener = firebase.notifications().onNotification((notification) => {
            const { title, body } = notification;
            // this.showAlert(title, body);
        });

        /*
        * If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
        * */
        this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
            const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
            // this.showAlert(title, body);
        });

        /*
        * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
        * */
        const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
        if (notificationOpen) {
            const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
            // this.showAlert(title, body);
        }
        /*
        * Triggered for data only payload in foreground
        * */
        this.messageListener = firebase.messaging().onMessage((message) => {
            //process data message
            console.log(JSON.stringify(message));
        });
    }
```

Please check. let me know if any other code required

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Yes i got the token and also the push notification from this test website. but for my custom object push is not getting created. got the response in log also

Comment: you need to parse your body

Comment: @ManojPerumarath In which method and how that is what my question is :( :( sorry i am new to react native and just copy paste this code from some sites and now not getting the methods

Comment: show the custom push object

Comment: @ManojPerumarath this one : {"_data":{"created":"21 Aug '19 09:24 AM","carpark":"0","message":"Your deals will be expired soon !\n1. This is Exclsive DOB Deals - SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem Date : 21 Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug '19\n2. This is Exclsive DOB Deals - SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem Date : 21 Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug '19\n3. This is Exclsive DOB Deals - SN\nTotal Price : Free\nRedeem Date : 20 Aug '19\nExpiry Date : 23 Aug '19","title":"Notification"},"_from":"759251633792","_messageId":"0:1566810334866452%98a4273ef9fd7ecd","_sentTime":1566810334859,"_ttl":3600}

Comment: @ManojPerumarath Have you found any solution ?